# JS Class: smartest way to create a variable inside a class without being called by the constructor

Tags: javascript, class

I want to create a variable inside a javascript class without the necessity to call it by a variable with the constructor.

for example, we have a *class A* that takes in 2 inputs (*a* and *b*). a and b are summed and the result is appended to an array *arr*. Where´s the best place to declare the array?

```
class A {
    constructor(a,b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;};

do_something(this.a, this.b) {
         let c = this.a + this.b;
         arr.append(c);
         return arr;}
};
```

where should i initialize *arr* without having it to be called form the outside ?

Comment: What do you want the scope of `arr` to be? Shared between every instance, or tied to a single instance? What's the problem with declaring it in the constructor?

Comment: So you want the array to be tied to the instance, but not set in the constructor? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? It's not very clear

Comment: @CertainPerformance Let´s assume i want the output to be in the form of an array. I want the empty array to be initialized whenever i instanciate  a class.

Comment: It *should* be initialised in the constructor, as that's where properties are created. What's wrong with that, what is the problem that makes you avoid the obvious solution?

Comment: @MHot So if you did call `do_something()` twice, you would expect it to append to the same array multiple times? And return a reference to the same array from both calls?

Comment: @Bergi yes, exactly. Is the constructor still the right place to declare this kind of variable?

Comment: @MHot Yes, it is. What makes you assume anything else? (Btw, it's called a property, not a variable)

Comment: @Bergi, its causing problems, thats why. Declaring  arr1 = []; inside a constructor doesnt work well for  me.

Comment: @MHot It's `this.arr = [];`. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning of the class definition, also you can not have this.a and this.b as parameters of the do_something.

```js
class A {
arr = []
    constructor(a,b) {
        this.a = a
        this.b = b
}
do_something() {
         const c = this.a + this.b
         this.arr.push(c)
         return [this.arr, c]}
}

const obj = new A(1,2)

console.log(obj.do_something())
```

Comment: thanks! could you explain the logic behind the fact that i cannot use this.a and this.b as paramters of the class method?

Comment: This is effectively the same thing as declaring the `arr` in the constructor. You also aren't referencing `arr` properly, and `append` is not a method of arrays

Comment: However, after trying this out i got this error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =".

Comment: @CertainPerformance duly noticed and fixed. Check now. I agree with you it is same as declaring it in the constructor.

Comment: @MHot try now, I forgot to add `this.` in a few places.

Comment: @CertainPerformance You are right, but would like to create an variable inside a class. Do you have an idea? (append is for sure not a js array method, but this doesnt matter right now)

Comment: @MHot no problem, please check the mark as answered.

Comment: @MHot ... if one accepts this answer then technical nothing has changed in comparison to declaring the array publicly inside the constructor function via `this.arr = [];`. As for the example code of @radulle one easily can log `obj.arr` which equals `[3]`. You might be interested in [private instance fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields#Private_instance_fields) via its *hash name syntax*.